# Python Pandas To split text in a cell to multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is in this format.

[image]

I wonder how I can split the Items ordered column into multiple rows like below.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
>>> (df.assign(**{'Items ordered': lambda x: x['Items ordered'].str.rstrip(';').str.split(';\s*')})
       .explode('Items ordered', ignore_index=True))

   Transaction ID Client Name Items ordered
0               1         Sam         Fruit
1               1         Sam         Water
2               1         Sam        Coffee
3               2       Peter         Fruit
4               2       Peter          Soup
5               2       Peter      Sandwich
6               3         Han         Fruit
7               3         Han        Coffee
8               3         Han     Ice Cream
```